# std::is_constructible doesn't give the correct result

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Originated from [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117869/70823) CodeReview topic:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class aggregate_wrapper : public T {
private:
  using base = T;

public:
  using aggregate_type = T;

  template <typename... Ts>
  aggregate_wrapper(Ts&&... xs)
      : base{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...} {
    // nop
  }
};

struct foo_t {
  foo_t(int) {}  
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::is_constructible<foo_t>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_constructible<aggregate_wrapper<foo_t>>::value << std::endl;
  // aggregate_wrapper<foo_t> v; // won't compile
}
```

How could `std::is_constructible<aggregate_wrapper<foo_t>>::value` be true when `aggregate_wrapper<foo_t> v;` does not actually compile?

Comment: Perhaps you're mentally conflating *constructible* with *default constructible* ?  An `aggregate_wrapper<foo_t>` can certainly be constructed, just not via `aggregate_wrapper<foo_t> v;` .

Comment: @M.M Nope, `is_default_constructible<T>` and `is_constructible<T>` (which means that `Args...` is an empty pack) are equivalent.

Comment: Not sure why this was reopened; the dup is directly on point.

Comment: @T.C. : Purely by accident!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C++ standard, in the `is_constructible` description, there is this innocent-looking quote:

> Only the validity of the **immediate context** of the [imaginary `v`] variable initialization is considered.

And then a note explaining what it means:

> The evaluation of the initialization can result in side
>   effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and function template specializations, the
>   generation of implicitly-defined functions, and so on. Such side effects are not in the **immediate context** and can result in the program being ill-formed.

My interpretation is that when you write:

```
aggregate_wrapper<foo_t> v;
```

You are using the default constructor of `aggregate_wrapper`, it exists and it is accesible, so it succeeds, at least in the *immediate context*. Then, the non-immediate context includes the body of the constructor, and that fails, but that does not change the result of `is_constructible`.

Comment: Then I guess `std::is_constructible` is not that useful anyway. Would rather write one myself that goes beyond this immediate context.

Comment: The real question should be why `std::is_constructible` stops at the `immediate context`?